# How to remove auto generated rows and columns by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have an HTML table which is retrieved by beautiful soup. The output is assigned to a list and then the list was assigned to an DataFrame

```
df = DataFrame(list)
```

The DataFrame while writing into CSV file, the CSV file is showing the output as below

```
0  1   2    3   4    5    6   7
1  A   B    C   D    E    F   G
```

How to remove the auto generated rows and columns by pandas so that output would be as

```
['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
```

so that the csv file will show output without auto generated values by pandas.

Thanks a lot in advance, Have a nice day.

Comment: Do you want a list or a dataframe?

Comment: After I posted my answer, I realize what you are desiring is not a csv file. I think you will need to clarify whether you want a Python `list` instance, or an actual .csv file.

Comment: @It_is_Chris can i please get it in data frame , so that i can input the data into csv in a single row

Comment: @BenY thanks for the answer, i actually need a python list , but when i was keeping them into DataFrame and then writing into CSV file ,pandas is keeping auto generated rows and columns into CSV file. can i only get actual data which is present in list into the CSV file without auto generated columns and rows by pandas?  like only A,B,C,D......

Comment: Did you give the answer I gave you a try? It saves a csv file but only the data.

Comment: thanks @BenY, it was working like charm :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for `DataFrame.to_csv()`, it has two boolean optional parameters, `index` and `header` which print the index column and header row, respectively. By default, both are `True`.

Try:

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False, header=False)
```